# update database sqlite android device

Tags: android, sqlite

I can't upgrade my android database:

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_login = "CREATE TABLE login (userJoomla INTEGER, idUSER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(20), email varchar(50))";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_position = "CREATE TABLE position(latitude VARCHAR(20), longitude VARCHAR(20), address VARCHAR(100), lastUpdate DATETIME)";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_favorites = "CREATE TABLE favorites(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, idSPB INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL)";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


public database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Create the table
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_login);      
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_position);   
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_favorites);  

}


// Method is called during an upgrade of the database, e.g. if you increase
// the database version
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,int newVersion) {
    Log.w(database.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);
    onCreate(database);
}
```

}

The exception I caught was:

```
 Can't upgrade read-only database from version 1 to 2:
```

I read here that it should be solved with;

```
    db = fav.getWritableDatabase();
```

But now I have this mistake:

```
table login already exists.
```

What should I do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);`, i.e.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myDatabase
```

Change it to the correct table name instead.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dropping the database and not the tables.

```
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);
```